# Updating a div size based on props in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a side nav bar like how it is shown on this website

https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

Now I'm trying to basically emulate the expanded nav bar and mini navbar toggle. However, I'm having trouble updating the size of the navbar in react.

Here is my nav bar component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SideNavBar extends Component {

    render() {
        let sideBarStyle = {
            'height': '100%',
            'backgroundColor': 'lightblue',
            'width': "80px",
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0',
            'left': '0'
          }
        setTimeout(() => {
            sideBarStyle["width"] = "300px";
        }, 1000)
        return (
            <div style={sideBarStyle}>
                sidenavbar
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SideNavBar;
```

I put a set timeout there just because I wanted to quickly test if it was possible to expand the div's width from a click event. 
But I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'width' of object '#<Object>'
```

How do I go about updating an element's size based on click events?

Comment: Can you try with sideBarStyle.width = "300px";

Comment: @HemadriDasari I have tried that and it does not work either. It gives the same error

Comment: Can you try setting width in state. Please check my answer  below

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SideNavBar extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        width : 80
      }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
              width: 300
            })
        }, 1000);
    }
    render() {
        let sideBarStyle = {
            'height': '100%',
            'backgroundColor': 'lightblue',
            'width': this.state.width,
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0',
            'left': '0'
          }

        return (
            <div style={sideBarStyle}>
                sidenavbar
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SideNavBar;
```

One more thing you no need to specify px explicitly in React. Just no is enough. React will take care of px.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake give me a min

Comment: Can you try now

Comment: this doesn't seem to work either. Just to let you know, I plan on implementing this with an onclick event so I don't know how the componentDidMount will affect it.

Comment: Is it. That should work. Ok NP you are saying you want  to change the width after onClick so then its very simple. You no need to use setTimeout and componentDidMount. Just do setState for width in your onClick handler function. Thats all

Comment: Wouldn't I have the same problem if this doesn't work?

Comment: Can you post your onclick functionality code as well. I will help you right away